# How i scroll multiple label Fields in blackberry 4.5

Tags: blackberry, scroll, horizontalfieldmanager, labelfield, fieldmanager

Hi friend's i want to show couple of data in blackberry screen through use of multiple label Field .But when i use multiple label field it's not scroll vertically and horizontally so please help me to solve this problem.

Here is my code

```java
public class Data extends MainScreen {

   BGManager objManager = new BGManager();
   public LabelField objTitle;
   private VerticalFieldManager vfmMainManager;
   private VerticalFieldManager vfmScrollManager;
   private HorizontalFieldManager hfmUsernameManager;
   private HorizontalFieldManager hfmPasswordManager;
   private HorizontalFieldManager headerBar;
   private ImageButton btn_Update;
   private Bitmap[] img1;
   private LabelField objLabelField;
   public TaskListField objTaskListField;
   public TextField objTextField = new TextField(TextField.TYPE_PLAIN, TextField.FIELD_HCENTER);
   public String strIndex;
   public LabelField objLabelField2, objLabelField3, objLabelField4, objLabelField5, objLabelField6, objLabelField7, objLabelField8, objLabelField9;
   public LabelField objLabelField12, objLabelField13, objLabelField14, objLabelField15, objLabelField16, objLabelField17, objLabelField18, objLabelField19, objLabelField20;
   public String strSerno, strDate, strAllo, strMob, strDetail, strRemark, strSldate, strEmail, strStatus;
   public int curentIndex = 0;
   public H_FieldManager objH_FieldManager1, objH_FieldManager2, objH_FieldManager3, objH_FieldManager4, objH_FieldManager5, objH_FieldManager6, objH_FieldManager7, objH_FieldManager8, objH_FieldManager9, objH_FieldManager10, objH_FieldManager11, objH_FieldManager12, objH_FieldManager13, objH_FieldManager14, objH_FieldManager15, objH_FieldManager16, objH_FieldManager17, objH_FieldManager18;

   public Data(int index) {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL_MASK);
      objTitle = new LabelField("Details Page", LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
      objTitle.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      setTitle(objTitle);

      this.add(objManager);
      System.out.println("Index1 ==" + index);
      this.curentIndex = index;
      strSerno = XmlHander.vectSrno.elementAt(curentIndex).toString();
      strDate = XmlHander.vectSrdate.elementAt(curentIndex).toString();
      strAllo = XmlHander.vectAllo.elementAt(curentIndex).toString();
      strMob = XmlHander.vectMob.elementAt(curentIndex).toString();
      strDetail = XmlHander.vectDetails.elementAt(curentIndex).toString();
      strRemark = XmlHander.vectRemark.elementAt(curentIndex).toString();
      strSldate = XmlHander.vectSldate.elementAt(curentIndex).toString();
      strEmail = XmlHander.vectEmail.elementAt(curentIndex).toString();
      strStatus = XmlHander.vectStatus.elementAt(curentIndex).toString();


      img1 = new Bitmap[3];
      img1[0] = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn-hover.png");
      img1[1] = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn.png");
      img1[2] = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("btn.png");

      btn_Update = new ImageButton(img1, "Update", ImageButton.FIELD_LEFT);
      btn_Update.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      hfm12 = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);
      hfm12.add(btn_Update);

      objLabelField12 = new LabelField("SRNo : ");
      objLabelField12.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField13 = new LabelField("SRDate : ");
      objLabelField13.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField14 = new LabelField("AllocationDate : ");
      objLabelField14.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField15 = new LabelField("MobileNumber : ");
      objLabelField15.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField16 = new LabelField("SRDetails : ");
      objLabelField16.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField17 = new LabelField("Remarks : ");
      objLabelField17.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField18 = new LabelField("SLADate : ");
      objLabelField18.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField19 = new LabelField("Email : ");
      objLabelField19.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField20 = new LabelField("CaseStatus : ");
      objLabelField20.setColor(Color.BLACK);

      objLabelField = new LabelField(strSerno);

      objLabelField.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField2 = new LabelField(strDate);

      objLabelField2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField3 = new LabelField(strAllo);

      objLabelField3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField4 = new LabelField(strMob);

      objLabelField4.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField5 = new LabelField(strDetail);

      objLabelField5.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField6 = new LabelField(strRemark);

      objLabelField6.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField7 = new LabelField(strSldate);

      objLabelField7.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField8 = new LabelField(strEmail);

      objLabelField8.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objLabelField9 = new LabelField(strStatus);

      objLabelField9.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      objTextField = new TextField(TextField.TYPE_PLAIN, TextField.FIELD_HCENTER);
      objTextField.setText(strMob);

      //      hfm11=new VerticalFieldManager();
      //      hfm11.add(objTextField);

      hfm10 = new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | MainScreen.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
      hfm1 = new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);
      //      hfm1.add(objLabelField);
      //      hfm2=new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
      //      hfm2.add(objLabelField2);
      //      hfm3=new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
      //      hfm3.add(objLabelField3);
      //      hfm4=new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
      //      hfm4.add(objLabelField4);
      //      hfm5=new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
      //      hfm5.add(objLabelField5);
      //      hfm6=new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
      //      hfm6.add(objLabelField6);
      //      hfm7=new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
      //      hfm7.add(objLabelField7);
      //      hfm8=new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL|VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
      //      hfm8.add(objLabelField8);
      //      hfm9=new VerticalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER|VerticalFieldManager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
      //      hfm9.add(objLabelField9);

      objH_FieldManager1 = new H_FieldManager(objLabelField12, objLabelField, true);
      objH_FieldManager2 = new H_FieldManager(objLabelField13, objLabelField2, true);
      objH_FieldManager3 = new H_FieldManager(objLabelField14, objLabelField3, true);
      objH_FieldManager4 = new H_FieldManager(objLabelField15, objLabelField4, true);
      objH_FieldManager5 = new H_FieldManager(objLabelField16, objLabelField5, true);
      objH_FieldManager6 = new H_FieldManager(objLabelField17, objLabelField6, true);
      objH_FieldManager7 = new H_FieldManager(objLabelField18, objLabelField7, true);
      objH_FieldManager8 = new H_FieldManager(objLabelField19, objLabelField8, true);
      objH_FieldManager9 = new H_FieldManager(objLabelField20, objLabelField9, true);

      objManager.add(objH_FieldManager1);
      objManager.add(objH_FieldManager2);
      objManager.add(objH_FieldManager3);
      objManager.add(objH_FieldManager4);
      objManager.add(objH_FieldManager5);
      objManager.add(objH_FieldManager6);
      objManager.add(objH_FieldManager7);
      objManager.add(objH_FieldManager8);
      objManager.add(objH_FieldManager9);
      objManager.add(hfm12);
      objManager.add(hfm10);

      //     add(objTextField);
      //      this.add(mgr);
   }
}
```

in this code I used couple of label filed like

```
objLabelField12=new LabelField("SRNo : ");
```

this typle of label field want to show horizontally and this are vertically

```
objLabelField=new LabelField(strSerno);
```

I want to scroll both side horizontally and vertically.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your label field Focusable.

objLabelField = new LabelField("Text", Field.FOCUSABLE | LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH)